# What is the word that describes a person who never believes you even when the truths are proven facts

Tags: phrase-usage

My girlfriend still accuses me of things even after the facts had been proven that I’m  not guilty.

Comment: More a question of philosophy than English. But I think the word you're looking for is 'Human'

Comment: Obstinance, stupidity, willful ignorance, delusion, distrust, paranoia... There are lots of terms for this, each with different effect. Also, you say the facts have been proven, but they apparently haven't been proven to her satisfaction, not unless she's willfully choosing not to concede facts she internally knows are proven because she's too proud or stubborn to admit being wrong. If so, my actual answer for what that person is would be "**TOXIC**," meaning you should run-- run fast, run far, and get away from her now, or she'll poison your life and make you an pauper in sanity and love.

Comment: You could edit and define the term you are looking for. The way your question is expressed now is vague, I would even change the tag. Have a look at the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to improve it.

Comment: Frame challenge: Is finding the most precise way to describe how you see her behavior really the best way to solving your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes it sound like you are talking about someone who refuses to believe you are innocent even though you are. A possible word would be **paranoid**:

The dictionary definition of paranoid is "characterized by suspiciousness, persecutory trends, or megalomania," but a more colloquial definition is that "it feels like everyone is out to get you."

If you are talking more generally about someone who just disagrees with everything, you could use

**contrarian** a person who takes a contrary position or attitude

or

**obstructionist** a person who deliberately interferes with the progress or business especially of a legislative body

Answer (score 0):

A denier.

noun: denier; plural noun: deniers

A person who denies something, especially someone who refuses to admit the truth of a concept or proposition that is supported by the majority of scientific or historical evidence.

"a prominent denier of global warming"